# condition in function parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new in C#. I would like to check some condition in function parameter.

I have to write function which in their parameter will check which numbers are greater than zero and return this numbers. How to solve it?

I have tried in many ways but none work.

Below is the code I have:

`int[] arr = new int[] {2, 3, -5};`

Comment: OK, let's start from the start - what have you got? What have you tried? How are the numbers passed to the function?

Comment: int[] arr = new int[] {2, 3, -5};

Comment: +1, bit harsh on a new guy... come on ppl -4 votes? all he's missing is some code and the ability to express his question clearly.

Comment: Yes, I'm new here and by mistake I have clicked "add comment". So for what these votes? Below I have tried to explain again my problem. 

Thank you Joe.

Comment: @paul, there's two joes here answering you hehe, confusing. Does my answer accomplish what you need?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> returnGreaterThanZero(int[] numbers)
    {
        List<int> greaterList = new List<int>();
        foreach (int oneNum in numbers)
        {
            if (oneNum > 0)
                greaterList.Add(oneNum);
        }

        return greaterList;

        // return greaterList.ToArray(); // if you want to return int[] instead of List<int>
    }
```

Of course you can use linq instead of foreach too.

Comment: OK, this is sample code:
        
        int[] nums = new int[] {2, 3, -5, 0, -2, 1};

        var result = from num in nums
        where num > 0
        select num;

And now, how to change above code to use condition (checking if number is > 0) in parameter of function. For example:

       private List<int> GreaterThanZero(n => (n > 0))
        {
            return ...
        }

I think delegate may be good but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: So returnGreaterThanZero(int[] numbers) isn't good because I have to have condition in function parameter, e.g. : GreaterThanZero(n => n > 0) { ... }

Comment: I got what you think about now, but I don't think it's possible in C#. If you want some warning if agrument contains below 0 numbers - you can add in foreach condition `else` part and raise some exception (like `throw new ArgumentException(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

On top

```
using System.Linq;
```

In your code

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 2, 3, -5 };
var result = arr.Where(x => x > 0).ToList();
```

This is how you do it using linq.

If you want greater than an arbitrary number then you can do `Where(x=>x > someNumber)` and pass someNumber in as a parameter elsewhere.